# How to check if a column has different numbers in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to identify all the columns that contain different numbers

```
for i in range(len(f)):
    for j in range(len(f[i])):
        if(f[j][i] != f[j][i+1]):
            print(f[j][i+1])
```

for example if the list is `f = [[3, 5, 6, 7], [7, 5, 6, 3]]`
I would like to obtain col 0 and col 3 but I am getting: `"list index out of range"`

Any help would be apreciatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `zip` can achieve a better solution:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(*f)):
    if a != b: print i
```

`zip(*f)` gives you:

```
In [18]: zip(*f)
Out[18]: [(3, 7), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 3)]
```

And now you can easily compare the "columns".

If you're a one-liner guy:

```
[i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(*f)) if a != b]
```

Answer (score 1):

You swapped the indices. So `j` is `0,1,2,3` and when it hits 2, the error happens in your if clause. Remember, the first index is giving you the index of the sublist and the second one the index of the item in the sublist.

This is correctly yielding 0 and 3:

```
for i in range(len(f)-1):
    for j in range(len(f[i])):
        if(f[i][j] != f[i+1][j]):
            print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=built#zip):

```
f = [[3, 5, 6, 7], [7, 5, 6, 3]]

for n, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(*f)):
    if i != j:
        print(n)
```

the expression `zip(*f)` iterates over a 'transposed' version of your list `f`.